# select the min of a set of sums

Tags: elementary-set-theory, summation

I want to the selection of the minimum element in a set of sums; I have a cluster with n elements. In this set, we want to select whats called the clustroid. The clustroid is defined to be the element whos sum of the distance to every other element in the cluster is the minimum. The distance is calculated using the function d(element1, element2).

How is this definition of the clustroid expressed mathematically?

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your set be $\{c_1, c_2, ....., c_n\}$ and let $c_j$ be the clustroid element.

You can define $c_j$ as the element satisfying the following:

$$\exists ! c_j ,\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}^+, k \leq n, \sum_{i=1}^n d(c_j,c_i) < \sum_{i=1}^n d(c_k,c_i) \iff c_j \text{is clustroid.}$$

As I don't know the exact definition, I'm not sure if this element should be unique or not. What I mean is, there are two elements with the minimum sum, then you can change your definition as:

$$\,\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}^+, k \leq n, \sum_{i=1}^n d(c_j,c_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n d(c_k,c_i) \iff c_j \text{is clustroid.}$$

Answer (score 0):

You have a set $S$ and a distance $d:S\times S \to \Bbb R$.

Now define a function $f:\begin{array}{l}S\to \Bbb R\\ x\mapsto \sum\limits_{y\in S}d(x,y)\end{array}$.

Since $S$ is finite, so is $f(S)$ so it has a minimum. Let $m=\min f(S)$.

**A** clustroid is an element $x\in S$ so that $f(x)=m$. So the set of all clustroids is $\{x\in S\mid f(x)=S\}$.

But it might not be unique. For example if you have two elements, both are clustoids.